# linking multiple listboxes c#

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm trying to create a listbox with categories and another listbox for items in each category. I want to be able to select a category in the first listbox and then the second listbox will change to display the items for that particular category. Its very common and I'm sure you can understand what I mean here. I was looking around for it but couldn't get any idea how to do this. I've created 2 listboxes for the moment and the values I want in it, thats it. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a winform with two list boxes listbox1 and listbox2 and this is what my Form1.cs looks like

```
namespace WinFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Category> categories;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            categories = new List<Category>();

            var categoryOne = new Category { Name = "Category 1"} ;
            categoryOne.Items.Add( new CategoryItem { Name = "Item 1"} );

            var categoryTwo = new Category { Name = "Category 2" };
            categoryTwo.Items.Add( new CategoryItem { Name = "Item 2" } );

            categories.Add( categoryOne );
            categories.Add( categoryTwo );
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            categoryBindingSource.DataSource = categories;
        }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<CategoryItem> Items { get; private set; }

        public Category()
        {
            Items = new List<CategoryItem>();
        }
    }

    public class CategoryItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is the InitializeComponent() code

```
            this.listBox1.DataSource = this.categoryBindingSource;
            this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            this.listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 24);
            this.listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
            this.listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(242, 238);
            this.listBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.listBox1.ValueMember = "Items";

            this.categoryBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Category);

            this.listBox2.DataSource = this.itemsBindingSource;
            this.listBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.listBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(286, 24);
            this.listBox2.Name = "listBox2";
            this.listBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(276, 238);
            this.listBox2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.listBox2.ValueMember = "Name";

            this.itemsBindingSource.DataMember = "Items";
            this.itemsBindingSource.DataSource = this.categoryBindingSource;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Working example (simplified):

```
private class CategoryItems
{
  public string Category { get; set; }
  public string Item { get; set; }

  public CategoryItems(string category, string item)
  {
    this.Category = category;
    this.Item = item;
  }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    return this.Item;
  }
}

private List<string> categories = new List<string>();
private List<CategoryItems> catItems = new List<CategoryItems>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  categories.Add("Cat 1");
  categories.Add("Cat 2");

  catItems.Add(new CategoryItems("Cat 1", "Cat 1 Item 1"));
  catItems.Add(new CategoryItems("Cat 1", "Cat 1 Item 2"));
  catItems.Add(new CategoryItems("Cat 2", "Cat 2 Item 1"));
  catItems.Add(new CategoryItems("Cat 2", "Cat 2 Item 2"));

  foreach (string cat in categories)
  {
    listBox1.Items.Add(cat);
  }
  listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  listBox2.Items.Clear();

  foreach (CategoryItems ci in catItems)
  {
    if (ci.Category == listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
      listBox2.Items.Add(ci);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example. I also need to access that listbox2 items indevidually through code and set theyere content. Through your method it cannot fint the items in listbox2 because they are just being created on the fly and not set in code. amm sorry my english is not well and its hard for me to explain, but does it makes sense to you?

Comment: @user933977 I updated the example.  Lots of different ways to do this, which include DataBindings, LINQ, etc.  You didn't provide any code to show what data you are dealing with, so I tried to make a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have a function that fills the second listbox based on the contents of the first.
2. Add an event for when the first listbox changes, and call the funcion described in #1